# Trying to test jQuery with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have created a really simple bill splitting app in JavaScript and am using Jasmine to test.

I'm trying to test this `calculate` function:

```
    function Bill_Splitter(){
      this.amount = 0;
      this.cost = 0; 
      this.tip = 0;
      this.diners = 0;
    };

      Bill_Splitter.prototype.calculate = function(){

        this.cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("cost").value);
        this.tip = parseInt(document.getElementById("tip").value);
        this.diners = parseInt(document.getElementById("diners").value);

        var amount = (cost + tip) / diners

        return this.amount += amount
        document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = amount

      }
```

However, I can't work out how to test for the numerical values (cost, tip and value) which are values from a HTML form that a user inputs.

My Jasmine test so far is:

```
    describe('calculate', function() {
        const form = document.createElement('form');
        form.innerHTML= `<input type="text" id="cost" value=2 />
                         <input type="text" id="tip" value=2 />
                         <input type="text" id="diners" value =2 />
                          <span id="amount"></span>
                        `;
        document.body.appendChild(form)
      splitter.calculate()
      expect(splitter.amount).toEqual(30)
    });
  });
```

Can anyone help? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the properties like you did with this.amount in your function constructor

```
 function Bill_Splitter(){
      this.amount = 0;
      this.cost = 0;
      this.diners = 0;
      this.tip = 0;
    };
```

```
 this.cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("cost").value);
 this.tip = parseInt(document.getElementById("tip").value);
 this.diners = parseInt(document.getElementById("diners").value);
```

```
describe('calculate', function() {
    it('calculates the amount due', function(){
        splitter.calculate()
        expect(splitter.amount).toEqual(30)
        expect(splitter.tip).toEqual(###)
     });
});
```

If your test cant find those html elements, you could add them inside your test:

```
it('calculate', function(){
        const form = document.createElement('form');
        form.innerHTML= `<input type="text" id="cost" value="2" />
                         <input type="text" id="tip" value="2" />
                         <input type="text" id="dinners" value ="2" />
                          <span id="amount"></span>
                        `;
        document.body.appendChild(form)

        splitter.calculate()

        expect(splitter.amount).toEqual(30)
        expect(splitter.tip).toEqual(###)
      })
```

Final code:

```
function Bill_Splitter(){
  this.amount = 0;
  this.cost = 0; 
  this.tip = 0;
  this.diners = 0;
};

Bill_Splitter.prototype.calculate = function(){
  this.cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("cost").value);
  this.tip = parseInt(document.getElementById("tip").value);
  this.diners = parseInt(document.getElementById("diners").value);

  this.amount += (this.cost + this.tip) / this.diners;

  document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = this.amount 

}
```

Comment: Thank you -  however I still get the same error, which is: `Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: This error message is because the test cant find de DOM element

Comment: document.getElementById("cost") // is null

Comment: I've updated the original post with updated code. The DOM element is a form that users input the numbers for cost, tip and diner for.

Comment: Updated my sample now with how to add html fixture

Comment: Thanks so much for this! However I am now getting this error: `Expected NaN to equal 30.` :S

Comment: Ok the problem is this line var amount = (cost + tip) / diners

You should use (this.cost + this.tip) / this.diner, otherwise it gets the DOM element.